# Allow link to work while adding active class

Tags: jquery, onclick, navigation, anchor, preventdefault

**Situation:** I have developed a simple navigation system that allows `.nav-active` to be added when `.nav-item` is clicked. Standard active function on websites.

**Expected Behavior:** When the user clicks on the navigation link, they go to the page and the `.nav-item'` retains the `.nav-active'` class showing the current page selected.

**Issue:** The addition of the `.nav-active` class function works but the link click does not take user to page, stays on current page.

**Assumption:** Because I am using `e.preventDefault();`, the defualt anchor behavior is removed and does not allow user to be redirected to the page.

**Question:** How can I properly utilize the active class function while allowing default anchor behavior? The only way I have gotten `.click() etc..` function to work is by using `e.preventDefault();`. Is there a better way of approaching this function?

**JS Code:**

```
var $navLink = $('.main-nav .nav-link')
var $navItem = $('.main-nav .nav-item')

$navLink.click(function(e) {
  $navItem.removeClass('nav-active');   

  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  if (!$parent.hasClass('nav-active')) {
    $parent.addClass('nav-active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

***[Link to full prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/z11vg2co/)***

***Edit:*** Because the removal of `e.preventDefault();` allows the `.nav-active` to be added and anchor to function as expected on the jsFiddle, I recreated the exact bug that I am seeing on my build. As you can see in Google/Firefox Inspector, `e.preventDefault();` has been removed from function (located on sources: scp-js/csl-scp-script.js line 20-22), it creates the anchor click bug.

***[See Beta link](http://beta.synchronygroup.com/csl-scp/)***

Comment: Removing `e.preventDefault()` works for me? It opens the link in a new tab, going back to the fiddle the element has the active class

Comment: I noticed that in the fiddle but when I remove the e.PreventDefault(); in my actual build, I can see the .nav-active but removes instantly when page completes load.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$navLink.click(function(e) {
  $navItem.removeClass('nav-active');   
    $(this).parent().addClass('nav-active');
});
```

Comment: I tried this code but I get the same result. The active state shows but immediately removes itself once page completes load. Here is a link to the full build in action [site](http://beta.synchronygroup.com/csl-scp/index.html)

Comment: It's odd that it works on jsFiddle but on the build it does not. Leads me to believe that it is a different problem or conflicting code. [See this link](http://beta.synchronygroup.com/csl-scpl)